# Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first

Tags: node.js

Hi I am creating node js restful api by using sqlserver database , i prepare get api when i am using that api output is shown in json format, while refreshing that browser gain its shows "Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first."error . I am adding code

```html
var express = require("express");

var sql = require("mssql");
var app = express();

//Initiallising connection string
var dbConfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'India123',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'sample'

  
};

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {

    // connect to your database
    
    var data = {

        "user": ""
    };
    sql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {

        if (err) console.log(err);

 
        var request = new sql.Request();
   
      
        request.query('select * from Login', function (err, result) {

            if (err) console.log(err)

            // send data as a response
            //res.send(result.recordset);
            data["user"] = result.recordset;
            res.send(data);
          
      
        });
    }); 

});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..');
});
```

Please correct me code . thanks advance

Comment: Is this happening on the first on second instance?  The first instance does not close the connection which would cause the second instance to fail.  No idea what is happening if it is failing on the first instance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// db.js 
var mssql = require("mssql"); 
var dbConfig = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'India123',
    server: 'localhost',
    database: 'sample'   
};

var connection = mssql.connect(dbConfig, function (err) {
    if (err)
        throw err; 
});

module.exports = connection; 

// app.js 
var db = require("db"); 
var express = require("express"); 
var app = express();

app.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    var request = new db.Request();
    request.query('select * from Login', function (err, result) {
        if (err) 
            return next(err);

        var data = {};
        data["user"] = result.recordset;
        res.send(data);      
    }); 
}); 

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running..'); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks Aikon Mogwai...its working fine..can you please explain what changes you exactly did??

Comment: You create connection each time when browser show page (and garbage collector must destroy it after query). It's no good because these operation requires CPU time. When app include `db.js` then connection create once and available for all modules.

Comment: This is slightly off. Your module.exports should be mssql in db.js. The reason being is that you create a new Request on the mssql not the connection.

Comment: Yep and I was getting the error `db.Request is not a constructor` when I was exporting `connection`. Changed to `mssql` and is working again.

Comment: @AikonMogwai I'm getting Error: Cannot find module 'db' - what am I doing wrong?  I have created a db.js

Comment: Perhaps `db.js` and `app.js` are located in different folders.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use sql.Connection() any more, instead use sql.ConnectionPool()﻿

Connections

Internally, each ConnectionPool instance is a separate pool of TDS connections. Once you create a new Request/Transaction/Prepared Statement, a new TDS connection is acquired from the pool and reserved for desired action. Once the action is complete, connection is released back to the pool. Connection health check is built-in so once the dead connection is discovered, it is immediately replaced with a new one.

IMPORTANT: Always attach an error listener to created connection. Whenever something goes wrong with the connection it will emit an error and if there is no listener it will crash your application with an uncaught error.

Create pool and use connection.

> const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({ /* config */ })
>
> Entire Article how to use pool and close pool.
>
> https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

```
var sql = require("mssql");

const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool({
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'Pass@123',
    server: 'SAI-PC',
    database: 'Demo'
})


var conn = pool;

conn.connect().then(function () {
    var req = new sql.Request(conn);
    req.query("SELECT * FROM Product").then(function (recordset) {
        console.log(recordset);
        conn.close();
    })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            conn.close();
        });
})
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: best answer for latest release (mssql 4.1.0 today) saved my life

Comment: I used the same as stated above but my test cases are failing since connection is not made before test runs