# Global connection already exists issue node.js

Tags: sql-server, node.js

I have connected MSSQl with node.js using below code

```
           var sql = require('mssql')
            var config ={
            server:'xxxx',
            database:'xxxx',
            user:'xxx',
            password:'xxx',
            port:'xx'
            };
            sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {

                if (err) console.log(err);

                  var sqlquery='';
                const request = new sql.Request();
                if(condition)
        {
            //query to the database and get the repo value
                sqlquery='select * from verylargetable'; 
                request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) console.log(err)
                   var repo=result.recordset[0].Repo;

         //query to the database and get the comm value
                  sqlquery="select commit from verylargetable where Repo='"+repo+"'"; 
                request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) console.log(err)
                  var comm=result.recordset[0].Comm;
                 if (result.recordset.length  > 0) 
        {
//query to the database and update the table
         sqlquery="UPDATE verylargetable set Repo='"+repo+"', WHERE Comm='"+comm+"'";
        request.query(sqlquery, function (err,result){
                 if (err) console.log(err)
                   console.log("record(s) updated");
               });
              }
           });
         });
        }
        else
        {
        //query to the database and get the repo value
                sqlquery='select * from verylargetable'; 
                request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
                    if (err) console.log(err)
                   var repo=result.recordset[0].Repo;
    //query to the databaseto insert new record
        sqlquery ="INSERT INTO verylargetable VALUES("+repo+"','"+comm+"',1)"; 
    request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
            if (err) console.log(err)
           });
        });
       }
    });
```

Based on some conditions have to execute queries. while executing, these queries are updated properly.but sometimes facing below issue

**global connection already exists. call sql.close() first.**

when i used sql.close() at the end i couldn't initialize connection next time.

Facing **connection is closed** issue.

I have separate method for database changes.I need to establish the connection at the start of the method and have to close at the end.In between have to execute all the queries.
please let me know how to open and close the connection properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Global connection already exists. Call sql.close() first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345149/error-global-connection-already-exists-call-sql-close-first)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345149/error-global-connection-already-exists-call-sql-close-first

Comment: you tried with below solution??

Answer (score 0):

sql.connect returns connection, in order to close the connection, just call close on the result.

```
var pool = sql.connect(dbconfig, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    const request = new sql.Request()
    var sqlquery='select * from verylargetable';
    request.query(sqlquery, function (err, result) {
        if (err) console.log(err)
    });
});

pool.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and solved it with below implementation,
For handling **global connection already exists. call sql.close() first**  we need to create a connection pool for mssql npm version 4.0.4

```
const config = {
user: '**',
password: '**',
server: '** or localhost',
database: '**',
pool: {
    max: 10,
    min: 0,
    idleTimeoutMillis: 30000
}}
router.get('/SQLConnection1', function (req, res, next) {
const pool1 = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, err => {
    // ... error checks 

    // Query 

    pool1.request() // or: new sql.Request(pool1) 
        .query('SELECT ID,Name  from Avatar', (err, result) => {
            // ... error checks 

            console.dir(result)
            res.json({'Result': result})
        })
})
pool1.on('error', err => {
    // ... error handler 
    console.log('Error ' + err);
})
```

});

Comment: HI @chetan mekha I am new to nodejs. Couldn't get about router also  have updated the requirement clearly. Could you help me to get it over